# how to fit datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable

I have a problem like this.
[datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwYT5.jpg)

I have so many column and not fit in screen.

I've try using `"autoWidth"` but still not work.

Please someone help me to solve this problem.

Thankyou

Comment: try vw. (View port width) `width:100vw;`

Comment: Do you want to add a horizontal scroll bar to the datatable? or shrink based on the number of columns in the view port?

Comment: where to put the `width:100vw;` ? in javascript or html ?
yes please, how to add horizontal scroll bar ?